Published strategies for an NPC in Dungeon of the Mad Mage
In Dungeon of the Mad Mage, the PCs have the chance to encounter the NPC Rizzeryl on the second level, although they might not learn important details of his identity.  Rizzeryl...

 ...is a drow mage but will likely be negotiating with the party while invisible.  He is a member of House Auvryndar, a House of drow who are found on Level three, and also a member of the Zhentarim.  The adventure says that Rizzeryl may reveal his membership in the Zhentarim to allied PCs but will not reveal his allegiance to House Auvryndar.

If the party negotiates with Rizzeryl and makes an ally of him, he may invite them to help him with a situation in another part of the dungeon, and will provide them with information on how to get there.

 Rizzeryl would like the party to strike against the organization of the Xanathar in Skullport, and will provide instructions to them on how to arrive there by traversing through dungeon level three.

However, in order for the party to do as he would like, it is quite possible that they will cause some collateral damage to allies of his along the way.

 There is only one way provided from the second level to the third level.  From the bottom of the stairs to level three, the party will either pass through the complex of rooms 5-7 or 18-20.  Either way, they will pass through rooms that are heavily occupied by drow of House Auvryndar who are very likely to attack adventurers on sight.  Even if they don't, adventurers being adventurers, it is likely that the PCs would attack first given the chance.  No way is suggested for Rizzeryl to direct the PCs to Skullport without them going through these rooms.  It is unlikely he could enable the PCs to pass through peacefully without revealing his allegiance to these drow.

It is not the purpose of this question to solicit a workaround (idea-generation and opinion-based questions are not appropriate for the site), and as DM I can do that myself.

 In my campaign I just had the drow expansion into the complex of rooms 5-7 be so recent that Rizzeryl was unaware of it, so he unwittingly was sending the PCs into harm's way, but there are any number of other solutions including simply redrawing maps.

However, in a response to this question, Nobody the Hobgoblin wrote that the Dungeon of the Mad Mage Companion "provides a lot of deeper internal logic and overarching motivating plot than the original module."  I am wondering how this, or any other third party guides treat the situation, and if any of them suggest other resolutions to this conflict?
While this particular situation is already resolved in my current campaign, if I like the approach that such a guide suggests to this situation, it might interest me enough to look to the same product for suggestions about similar modifications to the official adventure.

I just edited the question to remove it, but it looks like you accidentally pasted the wrong link there.

@GuybrushMcKenzie Indeed, copy-paste retention error.  I appreciate you taking the time to track down the question I was referring to.

I'm confused,  What is the question being asked?

@PlayPatrice "How [does] this [Dungeon of the Mad Mage Companion], or other third party guides treat the situation, and if any of them suggest other resolutions to this conflict."

@Negdo I realize that "third party publisher" is vague, but my intent is something beyond a reddit post.  Something like DriveThruRPG.  I'm not discounting the value of your take on why this is not a conflict, but as a 'standalone' post it does not connect me to other material about DotMM that I might want to investigate.
